# Python - sum all values by moving range

Tags: python

Actually I'm calculating throughput given certain window size. 
However, I don't know how to accumulate the values by window. For instance:

```
time = [0.9, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.3, 2.6]
value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

After window size with 1 is applied, I should get

```
new_value = [1, 5, 15]
```

I've thought of using indexes of data frame but not sure how I can realize it since I'm new to python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `itertools.groupby` with a custom grouping function

```
from itertools import groupby

def f(time, values, dt=1):
    vit = iter(values)
    return [sum(v for _, v in zip(g, vit)) for _, g in groupby(time, lambda x: x // dt)]
```

```
In [14]: f([0.9, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.3, 2.6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
Out[14]: [1, 5, 15]

In [15]: f([0.9, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.3, 2.6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dt=2)
Out[15]: [6, 15]
```

Note that for the window of size 1 you could simply use `groupby(time, int)`.

Comment: Nice. Note that depending on OP's needs, it might be necessary to sort the values first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
time = [0.9, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.3, 2.6]
value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
for t,v in zip(time, value):
    counter[int(t)] += v

print(sorted(counter.items()))
# [(0, 1), (1, 5), (2, 15)]
```